# Conditional format based upon the date string

Tags: excel, date, conditional-statements, instr

In my table I have the date in the format  "dddd  , mmmm dd, yyyy". So  for example "Sunday ,July 05,2020". I want the macro to format cells that have the word "Sunday" in and can't get it to work. I can change it to the dd string (ie 17) or the yyyy string (ie 2020) and it works, but not the dddd or mmmm strings which contain text.

```
Sub colour()
Dim rng As range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim cell As range
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = range("J2:J" & lastRow)
For Each cell In rng
'If I change "Sunday" to "17" for example, or "2020", the routine works, but I cannot get it to find 
'the dddd string
If InStr(cell.Value, "Sunday") > 0 Then
range(cell.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 19
Else
range(cell.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Dates are numbers in Excel, the rest is just formatting. You could try `cell.text` instead of value.

Comment: Eureka! Thank you that worked. I'd like to modify my code to highlight the whole row and would welcome any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Stephen,

You can do this directly on the sheet:
[image]

Or by code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub HighlightSundays()

   Dim rng As Range

   Set rng = Range("A1:A21")
   
      With rng
          .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
           Formula1:="=WEEKDAY(A1)=7"
          .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

        With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
           .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        
        .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = True
        
     End With
      
End Sub
```

HTH